# Kids/YA chapter book series with a group of kids from 2006ish and I think the title is an acronym or looks/sounds like the word "people"

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, childrens-novel

I don't remember much but the cover was pretty simple, just one color. Gave me Stargirl vibes.  It was about a group of kids. They had an acronym for what they called either themselves or the adults and it had the word people in it? It was a series of 3 or more books. One of them (or all of them?) have a spaceship involved. It was a super simple book, nothing like Series of Unfortunate Events or Hunger Games.

Comment: Did the kids have any sort of extra powers or did they just have a spaceship?

Comment: How old are the kids? What sort of things do they do or actions do they take? Are they based on Earth or somewhere else? Is this set in the near future or some different time period? What was "simple" about it (unlike ASoUE or THG)?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this is the AstroKids series by Robert Elmer. It's about some kids--Buzz, Miko, Mir, DeeBee, and Tag--who live on a space station. The kids call themselves the AstroKids, which doesn't contain the word people but it does contain the word kids.

They are simple books, maybe a second or third grade reading level. The covers are simple with one primary color, as you said. There are more than three--the boxed set I have includes five, but I believe there are ten altogether.

The first book is [The Great Galaxy Goof.](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3037136-the-great-galaxy-goof)

[image: Cover art for The Great Galaxy Goof, by Robert Elmer. A purplish-blue background, and in the foreground a cartoon drawing of a boy and a girl on a spaceship or space station, running from a small floating robot with three eyes.]

Here a link to the [whole series on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/series/68457-astrokids).